# How to use libraries in webpack modules the right way

Tags: javascript, webpack

Whats best practice for using libs like lodash in modules bundled by webpack?

1.
require it to a global variable

```
window._ = require('lodash');
```

2.
webpack conf

```
new webpack.ProvidePlugin({ _: 'lodash' });
```

3.
Require it in a module if I want to use lodash in that module like

```
let _ = require('lodash');
```

or

```
import _ from lodash;
```

4.
import only the functions I want to use in the current module from lodash like

```
import { find, map } from 'lodash';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import { find, map } from 'lodash';
```

should be used to favor three shaking